# ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "r"

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am running the following query but getting invalid reference error on "**r.teamId**". I found many answers about this but most of them suggested to convert implicit join to explicit. In my case, I think the query has already explicit join. How can I resolve this error?

```
select r.teamId,sum(r.amount),count(r.id),sum(r.distance),s.start_date
from runs r inner join ( SELECT team.id,league.start_date,league.end_date FROM league join team 
ON league.id =team.league_id where r.teamId = team.id) s
on s.id = r.teamId
where r.teamId IS Not NULL 
group by r.teamId,s.start_date
order by sum(r.amount) desc;
```

Comment: Change this to `r.teamId` or `r."teamId"`.  Your problem is the quotes.  I vote to close such questions as a simple typographical error.

Comment: Just remove `where "r.teamId" = team.id` -- you cannot correlated subqueries like that.  You're already doing this in your `join`...

Comment: @GordonLinoff  r."teamId" is for highlighting the error occurrence only.

Comment: @NishantKhandelwal - Your edit doesn't change the fact that you cannot correlate your subquery like that.  Remove `where r.teamId = team.id` from the subquery and your query should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the useless parentheses and derived tables, then you won't be confused by wrong aliases:

```
select r.teamId,
       sum(r.amount),
       count(r.id),
       sum(r.distance), 
       l.start_date
from runs r 
  join team on r.teamid = team.id 
  join league l on l.id = team.league_id
where r.teamId IS Not NULL 
group by r.teamId, l.start_date
order by sum(r.amount) desc;
```